# how to parse search keyword right after www.domain.com/search.php?KEYWORDS-HERE [Search Function]

Tags: php

How to i parse from www.domain.com/search.php?(KEYWORDS AS ENTERED) ?
Is there anyway to set whatever that the user entered as variable $snoop?

Can anybody enlighten me? I am stuck,drained and out of idea.

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search" action="search.php?<?php echo $snoop?>" method="get">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">

          </div>  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>    

    </form>
```

Comment: you mean the contents of $_GET?

Comment: @Einacio - or possibly $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']

Comment: @andrewsi thank you. it worked for me! :D also thanks to the rest who attempted !

Answer (score 1):

Give a name to your input, like 'q' for query:

```
<input type="text" name="q" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
```

That will give a URL like `www.domain.com/search.php?q=USERINPUT`

Now you can  access q via the $_GET global

```
$_GET['q'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the php $_GET or $_REQUEST method to get a variable in the browser bar.

Example (using your code):

Let's say we have the following link: http://example.com/index.php?s=a

Than we will have:

```
  //Modifications
  <?php 
   $snoop = $_GET['s']; //(or request)

   ?>
  //       
  <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search" action="search.php?
   <?php echo $snoop?>" method="get">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">

      </div>  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>    

</form>
```

Ps. You can use this if you already know the name of the keyword in the browser bar.